# Mathematical expressions on html/php checkboxes

Tags: php, html

I have a table in html which lists review entries then scores them using a drop down box. I am wondering how to count the results:

```
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-price-editable" >
            <div class="views-row-edit-static"></div><div class="views-row-edit-edit"><div class="field-type-list-text field-name-field-price field-widget-options-buttons form-wrapper" id="edit-node-59200313-field-price"><div class="form-item form-type-radios form-item-node-59200313-field-price-und">
  <label for="edit-node-59200313-field-price-und">Price <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <div id="edit-node-59200313-field-price-und" class="form-radios"><div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-node-59200313-field-price-und">
 <input type="radio" id="edit-node-59200313-field-price-und-no-mention" name="node[59200313][field_price][und]" value="no mention" checked="checked" class="form-radio" />  <label class="option" for="edit-node-59200313-field-price-und-no-mention">No Mention </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-node-59200313-field-price-und">
 <input type="radio" id="edit-node-59200313-field-price-und-positive" name="node[59200313][field_price][und]" value="positive" class="form-radio" />  <label class="option" for="edit-node-59200313-field-price-und-positive">Positive </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-node-59200313-field-price-und">
 <input type="radio" id="edit-node-59200313-field-price-und-negative" name="node[59200313][field_price][und]" value="negative" class="form-radio" />  <label class="option" for="edit-node-59200313-field-price-und-negative">Negative </label>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div></div>          </td>
```

There are 3 options: 1) "No Mention" 2) Positive 3) Negative

In the code, the field 'Service' has been scored 'positive'.

How do I count these values up, so I can see how many 'Positives' there are in my 'Service' column? The website is run on php so I'd assume I can use this but as the fields are not numeric I am not so sure. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a database to store the results?

Comment: This is on a content management system already, so yes I suppose I am.

Comment: Then it depends on the CMS that is being used. Is it Joomla? Droopal? WordPress?

Comment: It is Drupal, I think this question maybe better for that forum. I thought there might have been some code I could place into a view that would count this stuff up, realising that it sounds not so simple.

Comment: I'm sorry Rich but things are almost never so simple hehe. That's why there's the View-Control-Model. You need to use a component or widget which takes votes and adds them up for you.

Comment: Yes I know! There might be a better way to do the field such as assign a number to it..I only really need 2 fields

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide us with more (HTML) code (the part with No Mention and Negative) for us to help you out but you (probably) only need to create a new variable and set it to zero and every time a field has the value Positive you just add one to the variable - but without the HTML and PHP code we cannot really help you more!

Comment: Because of stack overflows very restrictive scoring system I cannot write comments until I get enough points!

Comment: @RichStevens please also add the php code where the values are processed.